# How to file taxes as Non-Resident Alien, using closer connection exception? (6th year in US on F1-OPT)

Tags: united-states, taxes, non-resident

I need to file my taxes as a Non Resident Alien, but I pass the substantial presence test, as I arrived in the US in 2012 on a F1 visa. I filed as a non resident for the years 2012–2016. I am presently still on my F1 visa (OPT) and working.

My company did not withhold FICA taxes on the assumption I am Non-Resident Alien. However, when I started filing my taxes, I realized I am considered Tax resident as I have crossed 5 calendar years in the US.

Under these circumstances, I want to file 1040NR-EZ under the "The Closer Connection Exception to the Substantial Presence Test for Foreign Students" rule of the IRS.

https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/the-closer-connection-exception-to-the-substantial-presence-test-for-foreign-students

So to file as Non Resident Alien, do I just need to attach form 8843, or do I need to attach any other documents as well?